# Servlet NOT_FOUND (GWT+AppEngine)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, authentication

I want to develop my first AppEngine application, that will also use GWT. Since I don't have any experience with GWT and AppEngine, I started with tutorials on GWT site, and after succefully completing Getting Started, I started working on http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/appengine.html

But I ran into a problem, and I don't have a clue why :)

I am trying to check if user is logged in, like in "Personalize the application with the User Service" section of tutorial.

But when I run the code itself, I get an error:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 404 NOT_FOUND</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /parkmeweb/login. Reason:
<pre>    NOT_FOUND</pre></p><hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i><br/>                                                
</body>
</html>
```

And here are my files:

**LoginService**

```
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("login")
public interface LoginService extends RemoteService {
  public LoginInfo login(String requestUri);
}
```

**LoginServiceAsync**

```
public interface LoginServiceAsync {
  public void login(String requestUri, AsyncCallback<LoginInfo> async);
}
```

**LoginServiceImpl**

```
public class LoginServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements
        LoginService {

    public LoginInfo login(String requestUri) {
        UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
        User user = userService.getCurrentUser();
        LoginInfo loginInfo = new LoginInfo();

        if (user != null) {
            loginInfo.setLoggedIn(true);
            loginInfo.setEmailAddress(user.getEmail());
            loginInfo.setNickname(user.getNickname());
            loginInfo.setLogoutUrl(userService.createLogoutURL(requestUri));
        } else {
            loginInfo.setLoggedIn(false);
            loginInfo.setLoginUrl(userService.createLoginURL(requestUri));
        }
        return loginInfo;
    }

}
```

**web.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app
    PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app>

  <!-- Servlets -->

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>loginService</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.parkme.parkmeweb.server.LoginServiceImpl</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>loginService</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/parkmeweb/login/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <!-- Default page to serve -->
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>ParkmeWeb.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

All this I getting called from `onModuleLoad`:

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    LoginServiceAsync loginService = GWT.create(LoginService.class);
    loginService.login(GWT.getHostPageBaseURL(), new AsyncCallback<LoginInfo>() {
      public void onFailure(Throwable error) {
             //this is where error is thrown
          Window.alert(error.getMessage());
      }

      public void onSuccess(LoginInfo result) {
        loginInfo = result;
        if(loginInfo.isLoggedIn()) {
          return;
        } else {
          loadLogin();
        }
      }
    });
}
```

Just by looking at this, I can't see any problems, and I should probably looking for problems elsewhere, but I would like to hear some ideas what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The handler is for /parkmweweb/login/, but you're visiting /parkmeweb/login - without the trailing slash.

Comment: I'm not familiar with GWT, but you're defining a function called 'login', and not calling it anywhere. How is login supposed to be called? The handler referred to in the app.yaml has to be a servlet, and the standard servlet methods get called on it to handle requests.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me too! (The trailing slash).  This is the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same problem. But I tried to deploy it to google. The servlet is accessible and no problem. It looks like being a problem with GWT + Eclipse, not sure exactly where. Hope they can fix it, other wise testing is difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I just restarted Eclipse and that fixed the problem.

Problem started when I switched from jre1.7 to jre1.6 both x64.